# How to pass the values of two fields into a function with Pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to do a query with **pymongo**. In the query, I need to pass two fields into a function which is defined by me. If the return value of the function is `True` the document will be selected. Here is the example:

The data for a document:

```
{"key1":value1, "key2":value2, "key3":value3, ... , "key10":value10}
```

I need to pass the `value2` and `value3` into a function as following:

```
def myfunction(value2, value3):
    # do some geometry calculation, eg.
    a = float(value2)
    b = float(value3)
    result = math.sin(a) * math.cos(b) * math.sin(a - b)
    return (result <= 0.1)
```

So, how can I do that with **pymongo**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite `myfunction` in Javascript and use that to filter your documents by [adding a where](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/cursor.html?highlight=where#pymongo.cursor.Cursor.where) clause to your original query.

```
clause = '''
    function() {
      var value2 = +this.key2;
      var value3 = +this.key3;
      var result = Math.sin(value2) * Math.cos(value3) * Math.sin(value2-value3);
      return result <= 0.1;
    }
'''

collection = query.where(clause)
```